# Nuget Package restore with git submodule

Tags: git, package, nuget

i have a project where i include 2 submodules from git. Both projects have "nuget package restore" enabled, the parent project too. 
The package folder in the two included submodules is not checked in, does not exist in checked out projects.
When building the parent project Nuget tries to restore the packages in the subfolders but into the wrong package folder!

```
"C:\Dev\git\oasisdb\odb_oasis_repository\ODB_OASIS_Repository\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\Dev\git\oasisdb\odb_oasis_repository\odb_oasis_rvm\ODB_OASIS_RVM_EF\ODB_OASIS_RVM_EF\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\Dev\git\oasisdb\odb_oasis_repository\ODB_OASIS_Repository\ "
```

Why does nuget not restore in the solution dir of the submodule?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NuGet not getting missing packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797052/nuget-not-getting-missing-packages)

Answer (score 20):

Nuget is restoring the package in the opened solution directory.

You can edit the .csproj of the submodule project and modify package dll references from :

```
   <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

to :

```
 <ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)\packages\Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: If you have to modify each project in the submodule you are effectively modifying the submodule, that is a big no. As @ Nuzzolilo says below, the library must not know anything about the projects that are using it. They should be agnostic. Sorry, but this is not a valid answer.

Comment: yes of course this should be use only if you own the submodule and know what to do with this trick. Thanks for clarification

Comment: I found that $(SolutionDir) includes the trailing backslash, so that can be removed.  It seems that the <HintPath> tag can cope with double backslashes, but the <Import> tag can't and will cause build errors e.g.   <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)packages\GitVersionTask.3.6.5\build\dotnet\GitVersionTask.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)packages\GitVersionTask.3.6.5\build\dotnet\GitVersionTask.targets')" />

Answer (score 9):

Found the answers:
For anyone interrested:

http://www.xavierdecoster.com/how-to-nuget-package-restore-when-sharing-projects-between-solutions

and

[NuGet not getting missing packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797052/nuget-not-getting-missing-packages)

Comment: Please mark as "the answer" so this doesn't show up in the un-answered pile.  Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely not. A library project should not need to know details about the host project that is referencing it. -1.

Comment: Did this change in the newest version of NuGet?

Answer (score 5):

you can use symbolic link:
After nuget downloads all packages to solution's `packages` directory, create symbolic link in submodule's root directory (names `packages` and link to the solution level `packages` directory).
In short - in your startup project add Pre-Build event that creates symbolic link between your solution `packages` directory to all your submodules `packages` directory:

This is the batch:

```
SET sourceDir=$(SolutionDir)packages
SET destDir=$(SolutionDir)..\..\submodules\saturn72\src\packages

if not exist %sourceDir% mkdir %sourceDir%

if not exist %destDir% mklink /j %destDir% %sourceDir%
```

Full explanation and source code: [SolutionWithGitSubmodulesAndNuget](https://github.com/saturn72/SolutionWithGitSubmodulesAndNuget)

Comment: Had to use a NTFS junction on Windows because my submodule's .gitignore wasn't ignoring the symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VS2015 Update 1 or later, you can [convert your project to use `project.json` to fix this](https://oren.codes/2016/02/08/project-json-all-the-things/).

In short:

- Run `Uninstall-Package <package name> -Force -RemoveDependencies` for all your packages. You may wanna copy-paste your `packages.config` in notepad before you do this.
- Delete `packages.config` from the project, save the project, unload
- Edit the project file and remove:

  - Any referenced `.props` files at the top related to nuget
  - Any `<Reference>` elements that reference a package
  - The `.targets` files at the bottom that reference nuget - usually starts with: `<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">`
  - If your packages contain Roslyn analyzers, make sure to remove them too.
- Save the file and relod the project

Add `project.json` with:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "frameworks": {
    ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win": {}
  }
}
```

Finally add your packages again, either by hand under `dependencies` or using `Install-Package` or with the nuget UI in VS.

I've also had to remove any `Microsoft.Bcl.*` packages from my projects because they explicitly look for a `packages.config` file.

EDIT: this (removing the `Microsoft.Bcl.*` packages will give you a compile-time error, even though the project will build fine, because the `.targets` file `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` adds will still look for `packages.config`.

To suppress this, edit your project file and add:

```
<SkipValidatePackageReferences>true</SkipValidatePackageReferences>
```

This needs to go to the first `<PropertyGroup>` that doesn't have a `Condition` attribute set. If there isn't one, just add another at the top, like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SkipValidatePackageReferences>true</SkipValidatePackageReferences>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer isn't getting much love - it's the least hacky IMO and not as tricky as it first looks. Thanks!

Comment: I don't even remember writing this but glad it helped someone :)